# Is it safe to pipe profanity through torsocks?

Tags: ubuntu, torsocks, terminal, proxy-leaks, torify

`profanity.im` is a console based XMPP client written in C. It doesn't (unfortunately) have any kind of proxy support built-in. Is is safe to use torsocks with a console based program like profanity?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, if it works with `torsocks` wrapping it, it should be fine.

`torsocks` can cause some features to break but it shouldn't result in any leaks under normal circumstances.

It's hard to tell without thorough review if any program is 100% safe, but outside of a few common situations where it may leak most applications should be fine.